# When sending update request controller receives null array in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm getting existing data from the database and putting it into a form.

While sending a request for an update, it goes to the controller but receiving null in an array.

Here is the view:

[image: personalinfo.blade.php]

Here is the user controller:

[image: UserController.php]

Here is the form that I want to update:

[image: Form to update]

Comment: Copy and paste or code instead of screenshots

Comment: Sure for the next time I'll share the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$user argument will be passed from router as a string not `\App\User` model, you need to change your controller method definition to:

```
public function update(Request $request, string $user) {}
```

And don't forget to change your argument definition from `\App\User` to `string` like

`@param string $user`

Comment: It works :D
Thank you so much. I was stuck in it from last week.

Comment: @MohsinAwan you welcome, mark the answer as correct when you have a chance